# How to insert html tags in template literals in response object NodeJs

Tags: javascript, template-strings

[Resultant Response in Messenger. But I need to bold username, phone-number, etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAmY7.png)

I am new in web development.
I also tried `\x3Cb>I am Bold\x3C/b>"` but didn't work for me.
How can I add HTML tags in this case?

```
let response = {
        text: `| --- <b>${username} Appointment Details</b> --- |
        \n| ------------------------------------------------------------ |
        \n| 1. Username: <b>${username}</b> |
        \n| 2. Phone Number: <b>${user.phoneNumber}</b> |
        \n| 3. Appointment Time: <b>${user.appointmentTime}</b> |
        \n| 4. Appointment Created At: <b>${user.createdAt}</b> |
        \n| ------------------------------------------------------------ |`,
      };
      callSendAPI(sender_psid, response);

//this is callSendAPI function
let callSendAPI = (sender_psid, response) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      let request_body = {
        recipient: {
          id: sender_psid,
        },
        message: response,
      };
      request(
        {
          uri: "https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/me/messages",
          qs: { access_token: process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
          method: "POST",
          json: request_body,
        },
        (err, res, body) => {
          if (!err) {
            resolve("message sent!");
          } else {
            reject("Unable to send message:" + err);
          }
        }
      );
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You may want to consider using a tool like [EJS](https://ejs.co/).

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what 'callSendAPI' function does, its hard to say what might be happening..

With that said, the template literal should have no problem putting any HTML. So you do not need to add the \n, as \n really does not apply for HTML so if you want to have it formatted you should be returning it all as html, so new lines you may want to use 
 or in your case, the pre tag may be more appropriate

```
response = {
    text:`<pre>
    | ---    <b>${username} Appointment Details</b> --- |
    | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
    | 1. Username: <b>${username}</b> |
    | 2. Phone Number: <b>${user.phoneNumber}</b> |
    | 3. Appointment Time: <b>${user.appointmentTime}</b> |
    | 4. Appointment Created At: <b>${user.createdAt}</b> |
    | ------------------------------------------------------------ |
</pre>`}
```

Comment: Actually I am building Messenger Chatbot. Here callSendAPI function is responsible to send the response to user. I also tried your code snippet but it's not work for me. I need to bold username, phone-number, appointment-time, and user created at. Now I am editing my Question to add image of the result. So, you understand well. 
Note: "\n" is working correctly
Regards.

Comment: I added the resultant image at the top. You may check by clicking the link at top. Actually I am also new to stack overflow as well so it not allow me to embed image directly. It automatically generate the link for my image. Regards

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like the 'messages' may have another escaping function being called, where it may be wrapping things or escaping html to prevent code injections. Are you using a lib for the chat, if so what one? Also, if you inspect the element in browser, what code do you see in its place? If you are using a framework for the chat there is probably ways to pass html vs text, would assume anyhow

Comment: I update my question by adding callSendAPI function. Hopefully you understand what is going on. This function (callSendAPI) simply take PSID and response and send to the chatbot user